# Read column / row merged in excel using python

Tags: python, excel

I'm having trouble reading the information from a spreadsheet that has merged rows and columns. I've tried using `merged_cell` to get the value but I don't understand how it works. Can anyone help me?

Using the script below, I can get the values​​, **except** for the merged cells. How can I get all of the cells, including the merged ones?

```
from xlrd import open_workbook,cellname

workbook = open_workbook('file.xls')
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

for row_index in range(sheet.nrows):
    for col_index in range(sheet.ncols):
        print cellname(row_index,col_index),'-',
        print sheet.cell_value(row_index,col_index)
```

Comment: Make sure to always add code formatting to your code snippets. Makes it a lot easier to read. Welcome to SO, btw.

Comment: The translation looks OK so I removed the Portuguese. Just so you know, you can try on http://pt.stackoverflow.com/ if you prefer questions and answers in Portuguese.